# How do I list all available encoding types available in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, character-set, encoding, unicode

```
SELECT datname, pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) 
FROM pg_database;
```

…lists all the databases, each with its encoding type.

However, I am trying to find out what are *all* the encoding types available in the PostgreSQL server. Can I query for all available encoding types?

Or are the only encoding types ever available listed in [Chapter 23.3 *Character Set Support*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or are the only encoding types ever available listed in Chapter 23.3 Character Set Support?

Yes. You can see the [full list in the source code, if you insist](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/113b0045e20d40f726a0a30e33214455e4f1385e/src/include/mb/pg_wchar.h#L238)

That said, it's *highly* abnormal to use any of these encoding except [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as an internal storage format. [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) should support all of the useful characters in all of the other encodings. If you find UTF-8 acceptable, the only purpose these other encoding serve is to eliminate the need to create an [ETL script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) for the `COPY` statement.

Comment: Right, I don't think it's exposed by any view/table, and `information_schema.character_sets` only shows the current DB's charset.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to get default encoding type set at the time of `initdb`?

Comment: *If no -E or --encoding option is given, initdb attempts to determine the appropriate encoding to use based on the specified or default locale.*

Answer (score 2):

I think it is OK to check the supported client encoding by the following SQL query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(conforencoding)
from pg_catalog.pg_conversion;
```